# Change popupmenu background color when using support library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-styles

I'm trying to change the background color of a popup menu in the actionbar, **when using Android Support Library v7**. I've been trying various suggested solutions that I've found, but none of them have worked, the popup menu background simply doesn't change from the theme's standard color. This is what I've done so far:

AndroidManifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

values/themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="background">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The values-11 and values-14 folders also have a theme file each, with the difference that the popupMenuStyle and background attributes are instead written as android:popupMenuStyle and android:background, since they aren't supposed to use the support library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same requirement , didu solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

in your style.xml add popupMenuStyle like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>     
</style>
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Removes the shadow around the popup menu.